How to set WebGL from the Kameleo API?
What would be the proper code set the WebGL for a profile from the Kameleo API?

you have a question and an answer with a part of the question. Please remove the 'answer', edit the question and add the text of the answer to it. So that the question contains the whole text.

Javascript:
const createProfileRequest = BuilderForCreateProfile
    .forBaseProfile(chromeBaseProfileList[0].id)
    .setWebgl('noise')  // Set WebGL spoofing type # Options: ('noise', 'block', 'off')
    .build();
const profile = await client.createProfile({ body: createProfileRequest });

Python:
create_profile_request = BuilderForCreateProfile \
    .for_base_profile(base_profiles[0].id) \
    .set_webgl('noise')  # Set WebGL spoofing type # Options: ('noise', 'block', 'off')
    .build()
profile = client.create_profile(body=create_profile_request)

